# How to Show output Jlabel another Jframe

Tags: java

When i input Text in the `JtextField` of `FrameIn`, and then click button OK, the Text will display on the `Jfield` of `FrameShow` the last frame is what I want, cause I still don't know how to make it.

I am using NetBeans GUI builder.

```
package learn;
public class FrameIn extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private String Name = null;
public FrameIn() {
    initComponents();
}
*
*
private void ButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    FrameShow show = new FrameShow();
    Name = Text.getText();
    this.dispose();
    show.setVisible(true);
}                                      
public String getName(){
    return this.Name;
}
```

and This my FrameShow

```
public class FrameShow extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form Frame1
 */
public FrameShow() {
    FrameIn inName = new FrameIn();
    initComponents();
    Label.setText(inName.getName());
}
```

So if i input Text in the `JtextField` of `FrameIn`, then output will display on the `Jfield` of `FrameShow` second Jframe

Output form this code is null on the `Jfield`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your parametres between the two Frame,

so when you click a your button, make an action that call your `frameShow`, and you can pass your values, in the constructor of your frame or you can create a field in your second frame and use setter to put your value, here is the idea.

```
class A{
   ...
   //action
   String v = textField.getText();
   B b = new B(v);
   ...
}

class B{
   public B(String v){
      this.label.setText(v);
   }
}
```

Second idea :

```
class A{
     ...
     //action
     String v = textField.getText();
     B b = new B();
     b.setLabelValue(v);
     ...
}
```

Here is your code should be look like:

```
private void ButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    Name = Text.getText();
    FrameShow show = new FrameShow(Name);
    this.dispose();
    show.setVisible(true);
} 

public FrameShow(String name) {
    initComponents();
    Label.setText(name);
}
```

Hope you get my point and you understand the idea.